# How is $A_3^3$ evaluated?

Tags: notation

I stumbled upon the expression below, but I don't know how it is evaluated. Any help will be appreciated.

$A_3^3 = 6$

Edited 1: It is a random expression that happen to be on a clock face which I hope it has a meaning in mathematics (image attached)

[image]

Comment: Looks like the cube of $A_3$

Comment: So it means $(A_3)^3=6$. Of course, it would be better to say what $A$ is in this context.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde  it's just a random expression on the clock face at 6 o'clock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without further information one can only speculate. I suspect this clock is not in English (I'd argue lg for log is unusual). In Portuguese, combinations without repetition are called "arranjos" and probably other (romance) languages have similar words starting with A.

That said, in Portuguese textbooks, and as I'm speculating, also in other languages, it's common to see:

$A_p^n = \frac{n!}{(n-p)!}$

Therefore: $A_3^3=6$

Comment: yep! I think lg is log base 10 too. Howver, it is quite unusual for me to use A^n_p for permutations (I usually use nPr or P^n_r) but I guess you are correct. Thank you :)